# Was Terok Nor the main administrative facility during the Bajoran Occupation

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Dukat used Sisko’s office on Terok Nor when he was Prefect of Bajor, so he had a presence there for sure. I find it difficult to believe however it was the prefects’ and what must have been a *massive* support staff’s permanent working space during a fifty years long military occupation responsible for the deaths of “tens of millions [of Bajorans]” *[Covenant](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/559.htm)*.

If I understand correctly, Terok and Empok Nors were primarily uridium ore refinement centers. Memory alpha says the spaceport “served as a command post from which the Cardassian Prefect of Bajor, most notably Gul Dukat, oversaw the military aspects of the Occupation”. So maybe just one of many command posts? Other more prominent and typical ones?

Was an ore refinery really the main administrative facility for this huge military endeavor? Seems kinda unlikely.

Comment: It might have been more convenient to have a custom-built space station just for Dukat and his staff, but that would cost money, and Bajor wasn't quite important enough to be a "no expense spared" deal.  So far as I'm aware only Dukat and perhaps a few other key personnel and personal assistants lived on-station, most of the administrative staff lived on Bajor itself.

Comment: Well, the invention called *delegation of powers and duties* is the basic concept of administration. You have several levels. That way Command post, while larger than other, sub-command posts, it's not huge. And Terok Nor has capacity for 7000 people. More than enough for admin/command post.

Answer (score 4):

The station was most definitely the command centre for the occupation, with Dukat in *overall* control

> 2346
>
> The Cardassians construct space station Terok Nor in orbit of Bajor. It becomes **the seat of the Occupation** under Gul S.G. Dukat.
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Pocket Books: Avatar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_-_Avatar)</sup></sub>

That being said, while there's no good indication that there was another large command centre other than Terok Nor, there were most certainly *separate Cardassian facilities* on the planet including [weapons yards](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pirak), [spaceports](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spaceport), [strip mines](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mining), [labour camps](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Labor_camp), etc, *each with their own commanders and staff*. It would appear that these operated more or less independently, with Dukat ignoring individual actions as long as productivity was maintained.

It's possible that after 50+ years of occupation, the prefecture runs so smoothly that a large command staff isn't needed since everyone knows what they should be doing, most of the time. Dukat only needs to step in when he suddenly finds that the ten weekly shipments of Uridium Ore from Rakantha Province has dropped to five.